# ModelBuilder Copy Features tool not updating shape when run as geoprocessing service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I have a model that uses the "copy features" tool and writes down a shapefile. When I run it as a tool, the shapefile is created. But when I export the tool as a service, if invoke the service the shapefile is not updated.

If I delete the shapefile created when I ran the tool, the service invocation does not create the shapefile either. No errors, no logs, no nothing. Maybe I'm missing some conceptual stuff here.

[image]

It seems that the image service is not available :(

```
f25_solucion = point geometry
departamentos  = polygons
```

The whole idea is to get all points that fall within certain polygons. The model runs fine, but runs only when ran as a tool.

Comment: Do the log files in ArcGIS Server indicate anything when the service is run?

Comment: You would need to provide info on how the source model looks; how the published model within the toolbox in arcgisserver folder looks; what messages do you get in ArcGIS Server Manager (set message level to Info in GP service properties window); what parameter types your model has.

Comment: @Fezter hi fezter, no. Logs are clean.

Comment: What do you mean the shapefile is not updated? Are you expecting a shapefile on your disk, like c:\mydata\myshp.shp to be updated from the GP Service? That isn't going to happen. Its going to make new output and send that to the client. Theres somethings you need to do to update existing data, but you'll have to script it. Even then, I'd step back and ask a bunch more questions regarding your workflow if thats what you want.

Comment: @KHibma hi, all i want to do is to generate a map service that exposes the intersection of points and polygons. that's it.